# WCF Client Syntax is different from Service syntax when using MessageContract

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I have a service which uses `MessageContract`

The syntax changes in client side. I don't know why. I am using Visual studio 2010 and target framework is 4.0

Here is my MessageContract :

```
[MessageContract]
public class DownloadRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string FileName;
}

[MessageContract]
   public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string FileName;

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public long Length;

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (FileByteStream != null)
        {
            FileByteStream.Close();
            FileByteStream = null;
        }
    }
}
```

My service Contract has this :

```
[OperationContract]
        RemoteFileInfo DownloadFile(DownloadRequest request);
```

And the implimentation is :

```
public RemoteFileInfo DownloadFile(DownloadRequest request)
{
    RemoteFileInfo result = new RemoteFileInfo();
      .........
      ....
    return result;

}
```

And I am geting following Error.

[image: Wcf client Error]

Any Ideas ?

EDIT :
I use basic http binding with streaming

Comment: Have you updated your service reference on the client side? Each time you change code in the Service, you have to update the service reference on the client!

Comment: Of course i did. But somehow my method call does not show objects (Message contracts) in the syntax.

Comment: I think I remember something like this happening to me. Try compiling on both sides, close the IDEs, and then reopen the IDEs. If I remember correctly, that seemed to fix the problem. It's like IDE wouldn't recognize the change until it was closed and reopened. It's a shot in the dark.

Comment: @Brian Thanks. But my code works fine when i switch to DataContract instead of MessageContract. I have been banging my head on this since last two days.

Answer (score 0):

from the error message, it seems you need to refresh the service reference again.
in visual studio, click menu Project -> select 'Add Service Reference...'.